# Setting shininess for glsl

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

How do i set opengl shininess float, so i can use it in a shader program with `gl_FrontMaterial.shininess`?

*I tried this `glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, 100f);`, but the highlights are not getting any smaller, so i guess shinines is not changing.*

**Edit:**
This is the fragment shader program where i use it:

```
varying vec4 varyingColor;
varying vec3 varyingNormal;
varying vec4 varyingVertex;
varying vec2 varyingTexCoord;
uniform sampler2D my_color_texture;
varying vec3 varyingEyeVec;

void main() {
    vec3 vertexPosition = (gl_ModelViewMatrix * varyingVertex).xyz;
    vec3 surfaceNormal = normalize((gl_NormalMatrix * varyingNormal).xyz);
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz - vertexPosition);
    float diffuseLightIntensity = max(0, dot(surfaceNormal, lightDirection));
    gl_FragColor.rgb = diffuseLightIntensity * varyingColor.rgb;
    gl_FragColor += gl_LightModel.ambient;
    vec3 reflectionDirection = normalize(reflect(lightDirection, surfaceNormal));
    vec3 eyeVecNormal = normalize(varyingEyeVec);
    float specular = max(0.0, dot(eyeVecNormal, reflectionDirection));
    if (diffuseLightIntensity != 0) {
        float fspecular = pow(specular, gl_FrontMaterial.shininess)*gl_LightSource[0].specular.rgb;
        gl_FragColor += fspecular;
    }
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(my_color_texture, varyingTexCoord)*gl_FragColor;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using fixed function, legacy built in identifiers in the first place? They're gone and illegal to use in later OpenGL versions (OpenGL-3 core and late). Just use a self defined uniform.

Comment: what exactly are you talking about?

Comment: are you talking about GLSL built-in variable gl_FrontMateral?

Comment: show code of the shader, do you use this shininess variable in the lighting calculation properly?

Comment: is it possible that i'm not changing shininess not in the right time, or i have to enable something before doing that?

Comment: Where's your `#version` directive?

Comment: @visDEVion: I'm talking about defining a custom uniform for the shininess value. You should do this anyway, because the built in variables mapping to legacy fixed function state are deprecated.

Comment: @genpfault yes... No version... How do i know what version to set? I tried setting #version 120 but the fragment shader failed to compile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use built in, legacy OpenGL variables. They're deprecated and make your shaders incompatible to later versions of OpenGL.

When you're using shaders, you use shaders. The whole point of shaders is getting rid of fixed function state and its API. OpenGL-3 core removed all the fixed function pipeline API, including `glMaterial…`.

Instead define all uniforms you require yourself. Also your code looks like a mixture of vertex shader and fragment shader. All that matrix transformation stuff belongs in the vertex shader. Doing it in the fragment shader is a waste of precious compute cycles.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of defining all uniforms, and setting shininess using cpu?

Comment: you could give me some resources about that

Comment: @visDEVion: I recommend you work through a tutorial on modern OpenGL. Nicol Bolas' is excellent, you can find it at http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut – it also explains in depth how to use shaders in a modern, future proof way.